# Insert multiple values in INT field

Tags: php, mysql

I got a multiple check box drop down that allows the user to select the number of students he wants to add into the class. How do i add multiple student_id in the student_class table? The field have to be INT instead of Varchar because I need it to auto increment. It shows an error when i tried to insert multiple value in it. Below is the output i need to achieve.

Thankyou

[image]

Comment: you can't do like this if you changed the data type of student_id to varchar then you can. but its not a good method.

Comment: if student id is auto increament than u cant do it

Comment: its better to create a seperate table for one to many relation, or if u cant than use the as @KrishnaGupta said. using a separate column.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its simple to so if the student_id is not auto_increment.
try to 
**add multiple  row's of student class student_id's for the same class_id's.**

Comment: How do I do that? As I'm using php, I will POST the result and insert into database. However, now I need to separate them into different rows, how do I achieve that?

Comment: insert into table (col1,col2,col3) values (1,2,3); @John

Answer (score 0):

You can do in 3 ways.

Need to implement 1 to many relation and need to add multiple rows for each check box value.

Secondly, you can make a third table and in which you can save check box value with parent ID. like user 1 have check box 2, 4, 9

```
1,2
1,4
1,9
```

Thirdly is not efficient but I would like to share that you can change type of field to var char and save all check selected values with comma separated. like for record User 1 check box values will be (2,4,9)